# Why does unwrap not give a monotonic phase?

Tags: matlab, derivative, phase

I am playing with analytic signals, and the computation of the [instantaneous frequency](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/hilbert-transform-and-instantaneous-frequency.html) often yields negative results. It is troubling, for a frequency, to be negative.

Although the concept of "instantaneous frequency" does not make rigorous sense mathematically, it is very common to derive it from the Hilbert phase. 
Without even getting into mathematical details, one thing that should make sense to everyone is that assuming it is proportional to the derivative of the Hilbert phase, it should always be non-negative if the phase is monotonic increasing.

I thought the primary purpose of Matlab's [`unwrap`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html) function was precisely to to ensure that the phase would be monotonically increasing. From simple experiments with random signals (see below), plotting the result returned by `unwrap`, it seems to be what it aims for anyway. My questions are:

- Why does `unwrap` not give a monotonic increasing phase?
- As shown in the example below, smoothing the output of `unwrap` seems to reduce significantly the amount of local minima; is there a smooth "monotonic filter" that I could apply manually to ensure that the phase is monotonic increasing?

---

Example code showing points with negative derivative on the unwrapped phase of a random signal:

```
% generate a random signal and compute its Hilbert phase
x = rand(1000,1); 
a = unwrap(angle(hilbert( detrend(x,'constant') ))); 

% uncomment to smooth the unwrapped phase
% a = medfilt1(a,10); n = find(diff(a) < 0); 

% show the unwrapped phase in a plot along with points where the derivative is < 0
da  = gradient(a);
neg = find( da < 0 );
mean( -da(neg) ) % average magnitude of negative gradients

plot(a,'Linewidth',1.5); hold on; 
plot(neg,a(neg),'ro'); hold off;
```

Comment: Afterthough: this might be more appropriate in the Scicomp SE forum.. Let me know if I should repost.

Comment: Well, the only thing `unwrap` does is interpret jumps larger than `pi` as their `2*pi` complement, assuming that the apparent jump in phase is actually due to the crossing of a branch cut of the complex function `angle(z)`. If your angles are actually monotonically increasing `mod 2*pi`, then the `unwrap`ped angle should also do that. If the angles are not monotonic, the output won't be either. For instance, an angle `phi=0.01*sin(w*t)` will be non-monotonic, but also invariant to `unwrap`ping.

Comment: @AndrasDeak The phase of the HIlbert transform is roughly comparable to a dilated time-course, you're saying it makes sense that a time-course makes backwards jumps?

Comment: I'm saying that `unwrap` shouldn't be doing any magic monotonization, it performs a very crude and simple "correction" on the input. I'm also saying that I know nothing about Hilbert transforms and instantaneous frequencies:) I'm only saying that the monotonicity of your unwrapped signal should be straightforwardly derived from the behaviour of your original data set. Are your time steps close enough? If the angle varies too much between two points, it will throw off unwrap and you'll get awful artifacts.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying, it's just a really annoying fact and I'm not sure what to do, the example also shows that the derivative is not just occasionally "a little" negative. So I guess the second question still stands; are there any monotonic smoothing options?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Checking your angle one by one, and if it would be *decreasing* (rather than absolute jump larger than pi), then take the 2pi complement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104190/discussion-between-sh3ljohn-and-andras-deak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, your issue is not with unwrap, your issue is with the massive amount of noise in your signal.  Your signal regularly jumps > pi/2 / step, with a standard deviation of > pi/4.  In such a situation, you cannot be surprised that a simplistic algorithm like unwrap can't ascertain which direction the jump should be.

Unwrap assumes all jumps x > pi, are actually jumps of size x - 2*pi.  If you have prior knowledge about how the jumps must behave, and unwrap doesn't satisfy those, then write your own unwrap.  Unwrap is only about 5 lines of "real" code.  You can see this source code by the matlab command `edit unwrap`

Comment: Yes, I basically arrive at the same conclusion from the Hilbert transform side. If the distribution of gradients of phases modulo-pi has a significant negative mass, then the information contained in the transform is meaningless essentially.

Comment: I think I'm just going to delete that question, because the "solution" is too complicated and not enough about programming to be interesting here on SO.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn I think it's a legit question.  The lines of what's programming, and what's math, and what's science often get blurred in my world.  Apparently yours as well.

Comment: Besides, @Sh3ljohn, it's very much frowned upon to delete questions with answers (on the basis of honoring the efforts made by others answering a question). Don't worry about it being not strictly on topic, worst that can happen is that it will get closed.